# OpenTelemetry: ActivitySource.StartActivity returns null activity when there are listeners hooked

Tags: open-telemetry

I use:

OpenTelemetry 1.4.0
OpenTelemetry.Extensions.Hosting 1.4.0
OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.AspNetCore 1.0.0-rc9.14
and runtime version: .NET 6.0 ASP.NET WebApi using docker base image 6.0-alpine3.17

I have 2 services A and B. Service A exposes REST API endpoint and also service B exposes REST API endpoint.

OpentTelemetry in service A is registered like this:

```
public static class OTRegistration
{
    private static readonly ActivitySource _activitySource = new ActivitySource(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name!, "1.0.0");

    public static void AddOT(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddOpenTelemetry()
            .WithTracing(tracerProviderBuilder =>
                tracerProviderBuilder
                .AddSource(_activitySource.Name)
                .ConfigureResource(resource => resource.AddService(_activitySource.Name))
                .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
                );
    }
}
```

A client calls service A endpoint and next this endpoint calls service B. In a call to service B service A randomly sends `traceparent` header which ends on sometimes `00` and sometimes `01`, for example: `00-000000000000000056473954588e71ac-36ae11cc57b1e9c1-00`.
When it ends on `00` service B creates null activities:

```
Activity? activity = _activitySource.StartActivity("TestActivity");
```

I double checked that in service B is hooked listener when the activity is created. I added some logs to prove it:

```
Activity was created as null. | OperationName=file.uploaded, traceparent=00-000000000000000056473954588e71ac-36ae11cc57b1e9c1-00, HasListeners=True.
```

```
Activity was created as not null. | OperationName=file.uploaded, traceparent=00-0000000000000000517d22c0e0b634be-5b066682501cc9b8-01, HasListeners=True, RootId=0000000000000000517d22c0e0b634be, ParentId=00-0000000000000000517d22c0e0b634be-a258d1b5dddfc7de-01, Id=00-0000000000000000517d22c0e0b634be-58691a9e53e3ae37-01.
```

I see that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.activitytraceflags?view=net-6.0 has to values None (0) and Recorded (1) so that`s why I suspect that 00 flag means that activity will not be created.

Any ideas why service A sometimes ends the `traceparent` with `00` and sometimes with `01`?
How to control this behavior to not have any randomness?

Comment: Did you find a solution here by chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last part of `traceparent` determines if activity should be sampled or no: https://www.w3.org/TR/trace-context/#trace-flags

[`Sampler`](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/ce2c5946faa9c961ea01d89c7aed83621865b67b/specification/configuration/sdk-environment-variables.md?plain=1#L96-L106) is responsible to set/determine if the activity should be recorder/created.

By default Sample is set to `parentbased_always_on`. It means that if the parent was not recorder, then the there is no reason to create new acitivity.

You can overwrite this functionality by call `.SetSampler(new AlwaysOnSampler())` in Service B or check why Service A decided not to record activity (maybe it is propagated from the client of Service A?).

Comment: In meantime I checked that calling .SetSampler(new AlwaysOnSampler()) in service B causes that activity is created always but I would like to better understand why Service A generates in kind of random why sometimes flag 00 and sometimes 01. I can add that service A has only one endpoint and the same service B. Service A endpoint is called always the same way by the same client.

Comment: I checked code  which generates traceparent https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/core-1.4.0/src/OpenTelemetry.Api/Context/Propagation/TraceContextPropagator.cs#L130 but there is no random thing there. It depends on context.ActivityContext.TraceFlags but I cannot find where TraceFlags are set. I suspect that it might be related with this https://opentelemetry.io/docs/specs/otel/trace/tracestate-probability-sampling/ but for now do not have full picture of this.

Comment: Maybe calling .SetSampler(new AlwaysOnSampler()) in Service A will also remove randomness and then Service A will always send traceparent which ends on 01.

Comment: AlwaysOnSampler() on service A should ignore any deciosion made by "parent" service or activity.

Still there is a chane that client ode service A is sending context with information - do not record any further activities/spans.

If possible, try to find the trace root. There should be information why it was not sampled.

Comment: What is it trace root? is it http header? where I can find it?

Comment: Trace root is the first Activity/Span created in this Trace.

You can determine it by finding activity/span which does not have parent and have the same traceId as your _problematic_ activity.

TraceId is the second part of this header: 00-000000000000000056473954588e71ac-36ae11cc57b1e9c1-00

Ref: https://www.w3.org/TR/trace-context/#version-format